# Bootstrap Modal Form in a PHP While

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop, modal-dialog

(first post ho yeah :) )

So,I have a very strange problem:

I have a `<form>` to edit some options for each users in a table.

So I use

```
while (blablabla req sql)
{ 
echo '<tr><td>['name']</td><td>['firstname']</td><td><button for modal appear></td></tr>'; 
echo 'my modal here';
}
```

(this is not the true code)

And... it work but it's look very very ugly (see **image 1** when the form is out of the while and **image 2** when I put the form into the while)

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Any solution?

> Code here >> http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/Tn4cUpjjos
>
> Code generated [only the end of one row] >> http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/Df4gvrJoS

Comment: show your code for modal

Comment: up! please :) really need of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one weekend of reflexion I'have finnaly find a way to solve this problem:

I put my modal in a exterior content (at the top of my php page) and in a new while, with the same request

**2 same separate request like that**

```
result3 = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_1");
result3 = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_1");
```

---

At the top of my .php page after <**body**>

```
<div header>
while ($ligne = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<form></form>';
}
</div>
```

And after, my table with:

```
 while ($ligne = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<table></table>';
}
```

That's all !

Correct my english or ask me if you have a similar problem like that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have just messed up the HTML. Remember, PHP is just generating an HTML, that you did not do properly. Do something like:

```
while (blablabla req sql)
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>['name']</td><td>['firstname']</td><td><button for modal appear>'; 
echo "</tr>";
echo 'my modal here';
}
```

*More suggestions:*
Inspect your generated HTML and try to figure out why wrong HTML was generated. Stop comparing UIs.

Comment: Can we have a look at your generated HTMLs instead of the UI?

Comment: hello
it's now ok  :)

Comment: up for my problem , still the same problem. 
I said 'its now ok' but it was for to have put the generated code in my post xD